# How to dynamically change spots of text in custom page?

Tags: plugins, pages, page-template

When I create a page I'm suppose to describe the content on the editor of Wordpress. When it's a simple text with some images its ok.

**But the problem is:** My custom layout has a lot of *deep HTML* and I want to allow the client to change the dynamic text parts easily, and avoid him  from having HTML parts inside the rich text editor.

E.g.

[image]

Wordpress has some built-in feature to accomplish that or some plugin maybe?

An similar idea is this plugin that I've found, but not for pages specifically:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/text-replace

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *static images*? Images that are always the same?

Comment: It's because I don't want to add complexity. Forget the images.. I want to have spots on the html that user can edit these texts

Comment: So you want the user to be able to edit the text of a new page using different editors for different zones? You can use several approaches to this. Have you considered using Custom Fields? If the chunks of text are somewhat limited, this might be the easiest solution for you.

Comment: If they are not, perhaps providing some context, example would help me think of the best approach for your problem.

Comment: hmmm. Custom fields are the way to go, but seems to limited. I found this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/installation/ and perhaps do the job more customizable.

Comment: I heard good things about that plugin. Give it a try. Custom fields seems to be the easier way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As @Luccas said himself, adding meta boxes for separate areas of content are a good way of tackling this problem. This can be achieved using [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/).

Although there are a number helpful plugins and libraries for handling meta box registration such as [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/installation/) and [CMB2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/), plugin recommendations are off topic here at WordPress StackExchange.